# Cant change element value Gecko browser (v45)

Tags: vb.net, gecko, geckofx

Im trying to change the HTML element value in a gecko browser (v45.0.32) but it is saying invoke member is not a member of gecko element,

```
 For Each solo As Gecko.GeckoHtmlElement In GeckoWebBrowser1.Document.text
        If GeckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("order_status_id").GetAttribute("value") = "1" Then
            GeckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("order_status_id").SetAttribute("value", "2")

            If GeckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("notify").GetAttribute("value") = "1" Then
                GeckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("notify").InvokeMember("click")
                GeckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("button-history").InvokeMember("click")
            End If
        End If
    Next

    GeckoWebBrowser1.GoBack()
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a 'Click()' method available on GeckoHtmlElement, so you can do something like below:
(cast and invoke `Click();`)

```
((GeckoHtmlElement)GeckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("notify")).Click();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no method called `InvokeMember` in GeckoHtmlElement, use `Click`.
2. The code you have specified should be called only from main thread. Use `Invoke` on GeckoWebBrowser's parent, if necessary.
3. To make sure, that one of your elements has an attribute, first check if this element exists in current document, like this:

   ```
   Dim element = GeckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("")
   If element IsNot Nothing AndAlso element.GetAttribute("value") = "1" Then
       element.SetAttribute("value", "2")
   End If
   ```